# How to extract pandas dataframe's rows whose indices are strings and contain a substring from a known list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe whose index is made of strings representing paths towards uniquely ID'ed videos across different directories, as in the following example:

```
>>> df
                           class
path                            
dir1/video_id1/frame1.jpg      1
dir1/video_id1/frame2.jpg      1
dir1/video_id1/frame3.jpg      1
dir2/video_id2/frame1.jpg      1
dir2/video_id2/frame2.jpg      1
dir2/video_id2/frame3.jpg      1
dir2/video_id3/frame1.jpg      0
dir2/video_id3/frame2.jpg      0
dir2/video_id3/frame3.jpg      0
```

I also have a list of videos I want to keep for testing as follows:

```
test_videos = ["dir2/video_id3", "dir1/video_id1"]
```

I would like to extract another dataframe whose rows correspond to the paths of the frames of the videos appearing in the list test_videos, such that the final dataframe looks like:

```
>>> test_df
                           class
path                            
dir1/video_id1/frame1.jpg      1
dir1/video_id1/frame2.jpg      1
dir1/video_id1/frame3.jpg      1
dir2/video_id3/frame1.jpg      0
dir2/video_id3/frame2.jpg      0
dir2/video_id3/frame3.jpg      0
```

Comment: str.contains:  `df[df.index.str.contains('|'.join(test_videos))]`

Comment: @anky,  yes thank you, I forgot that I could join the list of testing videos as you mentioned. Thank you so much!